# How can I have different catalog image sizes for different categories

Tags: php

I am building the website cuff and collar - www.cuffandcollar.com.au.

There are two different categories, one being tailor made shirts, the other being bow ties.

The tailor made shirts look great with the image thumbnails being the size they are, but the bow ties look terrible - there is far too much white space between the images.

**My question is: Is there a way to have a different template for different categories, with different sized thumbnail images?**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use separate `handle` for particular category.

```
<CATEGORY_{ID}>
```

Example:

```
<CATEGORY_5>
<reference name="content">
.....
</reference>
 </CATEGORY_5>
```

So you can change the product list template file for separate Category.

Ref [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19229441/magento-find-a-layout-handle-for-product-category-page) link

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I think this is probably a better method, I'll try it out.

Answer (score -1):

i ended up finding this post which answered the question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22317847/in-magento-how-can-i-show-different-different-list-phtml-and-view-phtml-for-diff

Thanks :)